# Hide column present in JSON of DataTable with server side processing

Tags: jquery, datatable, html-table

I followed this post: [DataTable: Server Side Processing in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531438/jquery-datatables-server-side-processing-using-asp-net-webforms)
I am using this code to initialize DataTable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            'bProcessing': true,
            'bServerSide': true,
            'sAjaxSource': '/data.ashx'
        });
    });
</script>
```

My JSON is something like this:

```
{    
 "iTotalRecords": "57",
 "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
 "aaData": [
  [
     "id001",
     "Name001",
     "Addr001",
  ],
  [
     "id002",
     "Name002",
     "Addr002",
   ]
  ]
}
```

I want to achieve same as below:

```
<table id="datatable">
   <thead>...</thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr id="id001">
        <td>Name001</td>
        <td>Addr001</td>
     </tr>
     <tr id="id002">
        <td>Name002</td>
        <td>Addr002</td>
     </tr>

     .
     .
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

**NOTE:**
To assign the id to `<tr>` I am using:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
     $(nRow).attr("id",aData[0]);
     return nRow;
}
```

But it is not hiding the `ID` column.
Please help.

**Update:**
I found a perfect solution for my problem.
I must create my JSON as below

```
 {    
 "iTotalRecords": "57",
 "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
 "aaData": [
  [         
     "0":"Name001",
     "1":"Addr001",
     "DT_RowId": "id001",
  ],
  [        
     "0":"Name002",
     "1":"Addr002",
     "DT_RowId": "id002",
   ]
  ]
}
```

For more information check this link: [DateTable - automatic row ID addition](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/ids.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `aoColumnDefs` to hide a column. [Datatables example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html)

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({
    aaData: aaData,
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        //console.log(nRow);

        $(nRow).attr("id", aData[0]);
        return nRow;
    },
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
        "bSearchable": false,
        "bVisible": false,
        "aTargets": [0]
        },
    ]
});​
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLhP6/1/)