# Pass By Reference to Generic Handler(.ashx) in Asp.net

Tags: datatable, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, generic-handler

I followed this post:[DataTable using Server Side Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531438/jquery-datatables-server-side-processing-using-asp-net-webforms).
Inside `default.aspx`, I am calling `.ashx` using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        'bProcessing': true,
        'bServerSide': true,
        'sAjaxSource': '/data.ashx'
    });
});
```

On `Page_Load` event of `defaut.aspx`:

```
Employee emp=new Employee();
emp.name="abc";
emp.addr="pqr";
emp.phone="123";
```

Where `Employee` is the name of Class.
How can I pass the Employee Object to `Data.ashx`?

I tried using `HttpContext.Current.Session` but is shows `Session` object as `null`.
Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Access the session Inside I used `IRequiresSessionState` interface as below:

```
public class Data : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
         // get Employee object from session here
         Employee emp =(Employee)HttpContext.Current.Session["employee"];
     }
}
```

Ofcourse to set an Employee object in session, on `Page_Load` event of `defaut.aspx`:

```
Employee emp=new Employee();
emp.name="abc";
emp.addr="pqr";
emp.phone="123";

HttpContext.Current.Session["employee"]=emp;
```

**NOTE:**
There are two interfaces present to make access available to `HttpSession` in Generic Handler:

1. **IRequiresSessionState**
       Using this interface we can read and write the session variables.
2. **IReadOnlySessionState**
       Using this interface we can only read and cannot write or edit the session variables.

For more information check this link: [IRequiresSessionState vs IReadOnlySessionState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039014/irequiressessionstate-vs-ireadonlysessionstate)